# Problem accessing skydrive

Tags: microsoft

I am running 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) and using the latest chromium browser to access MS Skydrive on the web. I just get a blank page with no UI. At the same time, I am able to access other services like outlook mail.

Additionally, my friend running 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) can access and use the full Skydrive UI. Any idea why is this seen?

Comment: Do you have flash plugin installed. If not run `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`.

Comment: yeah, I do have the latest version of flash installed. I read in some article that skydrive required MS silverlight earlier, but no more. Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have silverlight to see skydrive UI, but that is for Windows only. Luckily there is an open-source project which implements most of the silverlight. It is moonlight.

Download this from [here](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx) and install as per instruction on the same page. It is a Firefox plugin, so I think, you must use Firefox for this. (but may work on  chromium also, not tested though).

After installing moonlight plugin, you need to install user-agent-switcher extension in Firefox. Then change the user agent to "Internet Explorer" 7 or 8 (I tested with IE7).

[Install the extension by clicking this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/). Then from Firefox menu  → *Tools* → *Default user agent* → *Internet Explorer* → *Internet Explorer 7*. Then refresh the page to see skydrive UI in your Ubuntu browser!

Comment: i have moonlight installed on both chromium and firefox.. skydrive still gives me a blank page.

Comment: @DeepanjanMazumdar, I have edited my answer. I as sure, you will get from it what you wanted. :)

Comment: thanks Anwar, that helped :).. but, now I am facing problems trying to open word docs, nevertheless, that's a different question to answer ;)

Comment: Moonlight show access forbidden(403).